# Postgres on AWS RDS: Create table succeeds but only creates a relation which I can not find anywhere and can not delete

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The create table query is as followed.

```
CREATE TABLE xxx (
    id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created     DATE
);
```

it returns :

```
Table xxx created
Execution time: 0.11s
```

If I now try to select then I get:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx;

ERROR: relation "xxx" does not exist
Position: 15
```

If I try to recreate table I get

```
ERROR: relation "xxx" already exists
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.12s
```

And to top it off. If I reconnect. Then I can do it all over again.

I am using SQL Workbench to connect to the database on AWS RDS.
I am using the master account for these queries.

Comment: I wonder if your `search_path` could be pointing elsewhere? See: [What is the search_path for a given database and user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56035/2541)

Comment: You have to elaborate a bit more. Namely what should I check @JohnRotenstein . As I am inexperienced in this part. This is my first time working with postgres. 
I followed this tutorial
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem and in retro spec it makes a lot of sense. The problem was 
that I was not committing the changes to database. I guess as I have never worked in a non auto commit environment then I did not know to look for this. Butting the create statement between begin and end like so:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE xxx (
   id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id     BIGINT NOT NULL,
   name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   created     DATE
);
END;
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PgAdmin to see if it helps. I have my Postgres RDS configured with PgAdmin and haven't faced this issue